# I need an SSRS expression to check if a value in one column exists anywhere in another column

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an employee database, which includes a "Names" column, and a managers column ("Mngr").
I need an SSRS expression to return True (or "Y") if a value in "Names" exists anywhere in "Mngr".
This will show if a particular person is a manager.
I have tried
`=IIF(InStr(Fields!Mngr.Value, Fields!Name.Value) > 0, "True", "False")`
&
`=IIF(InStr(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Mngr.Value) > 0, "True", "False")`
but neither work.  Both return False, where it should be True (I swapped the cols around as I couldn't quite understand the syntax of the expression)
After researching, I have a 2nd DataSet that just holds managers ("Mngrs"), and tried this
`=IIF(Not IsNothing(LookupSet(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Mngr.Value, Fields!Mngrs.Value, "DataSet2").Length > 0, True, False)`
which wouldn't even run.

So I'm a bit stuck. I'm sure there must be an expression that can do this - so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second dataset to do this, you need to use `LOOKUP()` but across your entire dataset, the first expressions you showed will only take into account the the rows that are in context, which will probably be just the row where the expression sits.

try something like this

```
=IIF(
    LOOKUP(Fields!Names.Value, Fields!Mngr.Value, Fields!Mngr.Value, "DataSet1") Is Nothing
    , "N"
    , "Y"
    )
```

This just looks for the `Names` field in the `Mngr` field and returns the `Mngr` field if it finds a match, across the whole of `"DataSet1`"`. If` Nothing` is returned from the lookup, the expression returns "N" otherwise "Y".

As a quick test a generated some dummy data and used this as my dataset query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Names varchar(20), Mngr varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Dave', 'Bob'), ('Mary', 'Bob'), ('Bob', 'John'), ('John', NULL), ('Anna', 'John')
SELECT * FROM @t
```

Then I just added a table and set the 3rd column to the `LOOKUP()` expression above

This gives the following result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan.  This works well - thank-you.  Unfortunately - it only works on the full report.  I have a Name parameter on the report, and when used, always returns 'N'.  I'm guessing this is because the expression only works on the filtered data?

Comment: This will work on the entire dataset result but if you are filtering the dataset in your query then you would have to revert back to having two datasets, one of which would be your distinct list of managers. Just point the expression at dataset2 (which should be unfiltered) and update the 2nd and 3rd field names in the expression to whatever they are in dataset2 (if dataset2 has the manager name in a field called `Mngr` then nothing needs to change other than the dataset reference.

Comment: Ah - that's it!  Success - it works just the way I want it to now.  Amazing.  Thank you so much Alan - very much appreciated.